# How to match data values with array values

Tags: php, arrays, match, explode, array-intersect

So i'm trying to match the values from the database with values from an array.

This is the data from database

[image]

```
$verdeel = explode(", ", $data['product']);

$getallen = array("10", "20");

if(array_intersect($verdeel, $getallen)){

for($i=0;$i < count($verdeel);$i++){

    if($verdeel[$i] == $getallen[$i]){
        echo $getallen[$i];
    } else {
        echo "no match";    
    }
  }
}
```

output will be now:

> no match
>   no match
>   no match
>   no match
>   no match

I just want to only output the values of the array that match with some of the values in the database.

Thank you

Comment: Array_intersect already returns an array with the values you want... So either you get null of an array with the values that are the same in the arrays to compare..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array)

Sample:

```
<?php
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
}
?>
```

or Did you mean? [compare to array](https://www.php.net/array_diff)

Answer (score 0):

```
$verdeel = explode(", ", $data['product']);

$getallen = array("10", "20");

$someArray = array_intersect($verdeel, $getallen);

if($someArray != null){
    //DO STUFF
} else {
    //NO MATCH
}
```